# Gbps and Tor... ("Volunteer relays carry 48 Gbps")

Tags: relays

On this The Tor Project webpage: https://www.torproject.org/about/jobs.html.en it is possible to read the following: "The Tor network's 6000 **volunteer relays carry 48 Gbps for several million daily users**".

What does **48 Gbps** mean? I mean, is it the Data Transfer Rate of the Tor Network? Or maybe it is the bandwidth of the Tor Network? Or maybe it's something else ...

Could anyone tell me what does it mean? Thank you...

Comment: https://metrics.torproject.org/bandwidth.html

Answer (score 1):

It means the aggregation sum of all the speeds advertised+checked by relays. Of course it **does not** mean that you'll have it full just connecting to the network.

Comment: It's the measured throughput, the advertised capacity is actually much higher at over 200 Gbps as per [metrics](https://metrics.torproject.org/bandwidth.html).

Comment: Ok. So 48 Gbps is the measured throughput of the bandwidth of the Tor Network. Right?

Comment: yes. Here how it works: a relay advertises it's speed - it can be whatever, even 1Pbps, but after that other nodes are starting to measure it by themselves in a distributed manner. And the consensus result of these metrics is the "relay speed" as it is considered by the network. An aggregate sum of *these particular* speeds is the number you're asking about.

Comment: Hmm, the bandwidth measurement is __not that__ distributed. Though some non-dirauth relays could be participating in the process, dirauths control all these measurements.